# Organizations not being displayed underneath my account

Tags: ibm-cloud, organization

I have 3 BlueMix accounts, each with at least one organization.  I am in an account with two organizations, and see no way of switching.  each org has at least one space.  This used to be part of the menu options but I no longer see it?[screenshot of menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgJxE.png)

Answer (score 0):

The option has moved in the new console layout. Use the menu in the top left to get to the dashboard, then along the top you should see your resource groups, regions, orgs and spaces listed and be able to get where you need to go.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this does not help.  I have explored every single menu option on the right including accounts, regions, etc (see my screenshot in my original comment) , I have gone into manage orgs and done everything I can possibly think of and I see no way to switch.

Comment: Try this: On the top left, click on the "burger" menu, choose Dashboard.  This should bring you to a page that then has a row of drowdowns along the top of the page, including the organization and space options.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it - for anyone who wants to reference, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2bxI.png)see the snapshot below...